# Removing second SIM signal sign from notification

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notification-bar

I have karbonn a9 plus smart phone. It is a dual sim phone, but I only use 1 SIM.

The second SIM signal icon with no network always shows in the notification area. I want to remove it from my notification area.

How do I do this? I have rooted my phone.

Answer (score 1):

The **Xposed Framework** can help you with this.

Read about the Xposed Framework and how to install it from [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/what-is-xposed-framework-for-android-how-to-install-it-guide/).
Verify if your handset is supported.
Here are some modules for the framework that you can look into:

- [Xposed StatusBar Mods](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.dr8.sbicons.sense) (still in beta, confirm phone support)
- [Status Bar Icon Hider](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-hide-statusbar-icons-clock-battery-t2768605)

Answer (score 0):

Root your phone. Install Xposed Framework and install a module for hiding the extra sim sign.

Comment: OP stated that their phone is already rooted...

Comment: Xposed sounds like a good approach here. But which module are you referring to? A link would be helpful. Meanwhile, there are plenty of Xposed modules around, your question comes close to "install some app from Play" without telling which one to chose :)